# How to split pandas column into two columns with strings and ints

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

Im looking to split the column Date range into two columns, starting date and ending date. However it split doesn't seem to work because it does not recognise the '-'. Any advice?

[image]

I tried using

'''
ebola1 = pd.DataFrame(ebola['Date range'].str.split('-',1).to_list(),columns = ['start date','end date'])
'''

However, it returns the following:

[image]

So (1) it doesn't recognize the '-', (2)how do I distinguish between 'Jun-Nov 1976' and 'Oct 2001-Mar 2002', (3) how to I include the new columns in the existing table?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `print (ebola['Date range'].head(20).tolist())` ?

Comment: ['Jun–Nov 1976', 'Sep–Oct 1976', 'Jun 1977', 'Jul–Oct 1979', 'Nov 1994', 'Nov 1994–Feb 1995', 'Jan–Jul 1995', 'Jan–Mar 1996', 'Jul 1996–Jan 1997', 'Oct 2000–Feb 2001', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Dec 2002–Apr 2003', 'Dec 2002–Apr 2003', 'Dec 2002–Apr 2003', 'Oct–Dec 2003', 'Apr–Jun 2004']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is used `–` instead `-`, so use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for `DataFrame`:

```
data = ['Jun–Nov 1976', 'Sep–Oct 1976', 'Jun 1977', 'Jul–Oct 1979', 'Nov 1994', 'Nov 1994–Feb 1995', 'Jan–Jul 1995', 'Jan–Mar 1996', 'Jul 1996–Jan 1997', 'Oct 2000–Feb 2001', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Oct 2001–Mar 2002', 'Dec 2002–Apr 2003', 'Dec 2002–Apr 2003', 'Dec 2002–Apr 2003', 'Oct–Dec 2003', 'Apr–Jun 2004'] 

ebola = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date range'])
```

---

```
ebola1 = ebola['Date range'].str.split('–', 1, expand=True)
ebola1.columns = ['start date','end date']
```

And then [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for add years from `end date` by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) but only if not exist in `start date` column tested by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
mask = ebola1['start date'].str.contains('\d')
years = ebola1['end date'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
ebola1['start date'] = np.where(mask, 
                                ebola1['start date'], 
                                ebola1['start date'] + ' ' + years)
```

---

```
print (ebola1)

   start date  end date
0    Jun 1976  Nov 1976
1    Sep 1976  Oct 1976
2    Jun 1977      None
3    Jul 1979  Oct 1979
4    Nov 1994      None
5    Nov 1994  Feb 1995
6    Jan 1995  Jul 1995
7    Jan 1996  Mar 1996
8    Jul 1996  Jan 1997
9    Oct 2000  Feb 2001
10   Oct 2001  Mar 2002
11   Oct 2001  Mar 2002
12   Oct 2001  Mar 2002
13   Oct 2001  Mar 2002
14   Oct 2001  Mar 2002
15   Dec 2002  Apr 2003
16   Dec 2002  Apr 2003
17   Dec 2002  Apr 2003
18   Oct 2003  Dec 2003
19   Apr 2004  Jun 2004
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a simple way to add the year from if it all occurs in one year. E.g Jun-Nov 1976 become start date: Jun 1976 and end date: Nov 1976 instead of start date: Jun end date: Nove 1976? Im trying to create a loop now using loc. (code in next comment )

Comment: for i in range(1, len(ebola)):
    ebola.loc[i, 'start date'] = ebola.loc[i, 'start date'] ebola.loc[i + 1, 'end date'][1]